# $Rank(A)\leq r \iff$ There are B and C such that $A=BC$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

Let $A\in M_{m \times n}$. Then

$\operatorname{rank}(A)\leq r$ $\iff$ there are $B\in M_{m \times r}$ and $C\in M_{r \times n}$ such that $A=BC$.

($\Leftarrow$) $A=BC\Rightarrow A=\sum\limits_{i=1}^r\sum\limits_{j=1}^n C^{ij}B^i\Rightarrow \operatorname{rank}(A)\leq r$

($\Rightarrow$) $\operatorname{rank}(A)\leq r\Rightarrow A_{m \times n}=B_{m \times i}C_{i \times n}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^r\sum\limits_{j=1}^n C^{ij}B^i\Rightarrow$ there are $B\in M_{m \times r}$ and $C\in M_{r \times n}$ such that $A=BC$.

Is it a valid proof? can it be $\iff$ proof? is there an easier proof?

Comment: What do you denote $B^i$?

Comment: Column i of matrix B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a valid proof, because as far as I can see you are just writing formulas that express matrix multiplication, and any reasoning that might be going on is completely implicit (which is polite for: absent).

A correct reasoning is much easier if you abstract away from the concrete matrix representation, which is just leads to distraction by the nitty-gritty details of matrix multiplication. Interpret matrices as corresponding to linear maps between finite dimensional vector spaces with respect to certain bases; lacking any specific context you can take these spaces to be of the form $K^n$ (where $K$ is you base field) equipped with their standard bases, but the argument will be independent of this particular choice. The rank of a matrix (the dimension of the span of the columns) is the rank (dimension of the image) of the corresponding linear map, because the columns are just the coordinates on the basis at arrival of a spanning set of the image, and the coordinate map is an isomorphism (so preserves dimensions of subspaces).

So now you are asking why the rank of a linear map $a:U\to W$ is at most$~r$ if and only if it can be written as the composition $a=b\circ c$ of linear maps $c:U\to V$ and $b:V\to W$ where $\dim V=r$. I don't see a proof that does both implications at once, but both of them are easy. Supposing one has such a decomposition $a=b\circ c$, then the image $a(U)=b(c(U))$ is contained in the image $b(V)$ (since $c(U)\subseteq V$), which has dimension $\def\rk{\operatorname{rk}}\rk(b)=\dim(V)-\dim(\ker(b))$ by rank nullity; then $$\rk(a)=\dim(a(U))\leq\dim(b(V))=\rk(b)=\dim(V)-\dim(\ker(b))\leq\dim(V)=r.$$
Conversely suppose $\rk(a)\leq r$. One can always factor $a$ through its own image $a:U\to a(U)\hookrightarrow W$, so in case $\rk(a)=r$ one can simply take $V=U(A)$, with $c$ the map $a$ itself but made surjective by replacing the space at arrival with the actual image $u(A)$, and $b$ the inclusion of that image into $W$. If $\rk(a)<r$ one needs to add $d=r-\rk(a)$ to the dimension of$~a(U)$ in forming$~V$, which can be done by taking $V=a(U)\times K^d$; now $c$ can be taken to be the composition $U\to a(U)\hookrightarrow a(U)\times K^d$, and $b$ the composition, with as first map projection on the first factor: $a(U)\times K^d\to a(U)\hookrightarrow W$.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive proof.
I did not understand the sentence: "One can always factor $a$ through its own image $a:U\to a(U)\hookrightarrow W$" and what the symbol $\hookrightarrow$ means

Comment: @gbox: The symbol $\hookrightarrow$ is used to indicate that a map is the inclusion of a smaller set into a larger set (and in particular it is injective). What is going on is that one wants to factor $a$ through an intermediate vector space of dimension $\rk(a)$. But the image of $a$ is exactly such a vector space; instead of using $K^{\rk a}$ (which would also work, but would leave more to be done) we consider the image $a(U)$ as an abstract vector space in its own right. What remains is to define $c$ as $a$, but ignoring vectors outside $a(U)$, and define $b:a(U)\hookrightarrow W$.

Answer (score 3):

No, the arguments you're using are not valid.

Suppose $A=BC$, where $B\in M_{m\times r}$ and $C\in M_{r\times n}$. Then the rank of $B$ is at most $r$, so also the rank of $A$ is at most $r$, because $\operatorname{rank}(XY)\le\operatorname{rank}(X)$.

If $\operatorname{rank}(A)=k\le r$, then a [full rank decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_factorization) of $A$ is of the form $A=XY$, with $X\in M_{m\times k}$ and $Y\in M_{k\times n}$.

Consider the matrix $B$ obtained from $X$ by adding $r-k$ zero columns at the right and $C$ obtained by $Y$ by adding $r-k$ zero rows at the bottom. Then $B\in M_{m\times r}$, $C\in M_{r\times n}$ and $BC=XY$.

You get a full rank decomposition of $A$ in various ways. For instance the [LU-decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) or the [QR-decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition).

Comment: Why $A$ is at most $r$? can't it be that $Rank(A)=n>r$?

Comment: @gbox The rank of a matrix is at most equal to the minimum between the number of rows and the number of columns. When you do a matrix product, the rank cannot increase.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple proof: let $u\colon \mathbf R^n\rightarrow \mathbf R^m$ be the linear map with matrix $A$ in the canonical basis. Note that $\operatorname{rank} A <r$  if and only if there exist  linear maps $f\colon\mathbf R^n\rightarrow \mathbf R^r $ and $g\colon\mathbf R^r\rightarrow \mathbf R^m$ such that the following diagram commutes:

[image]

i.e. such that $u=g\circ f$.

Indeed, if  $\operatorname{rank} A=\operatorname{rank} u =s\leq r$ there exists an isomorphism $\varphi\colon\operatorname{Im} u \simeq \mathbf R^s$. Consider the linear map $\bar u\colon \mathbf R^n\rightarrow \operatorname{Im}u, x\mapsto u(x)$, the  injection $i\colon\mathbf R^ s\hookrightarrow \mathbf R^r, \enspace x\mapsto (x,0,\dots,0)$ ($r-s$ zeroes) and set $f=i\circ \varphi\circ\bar u$.

Now for $g$: let $j\colon\operatorname{Im} u \hookrightarrow \mathbf R^m$ be the canonical injection and $p\colon \mathbf R^r\rightarrow\mathbf R^ s$ the projection on the first $r$ factors. Set $g=j\circ \varphi^{-1}\circ p$. We have:
$$ g\circ f=(j\circ\varphi^{-1}\circ p)\circ(i\circ \varphi\circ\bar u)=j\circ(\varphi^{-1}\circ (p\circ i)\circ \varphi)\circ\bar u=j\circ\varphi^{-1}\circ \varphi\circ\bar u=j\circ u=u. $$

Conversely, if $u=g\circ f$ as indicated, $\operatorname{rank} u \le\operatorname{rank} g\le r$.

Now if  $B\in\mathcal M_{m\times r}$ and $C\in\mathcal M_{r\times n}$ are the matrices associated with $g$ and $f$ respectively, the decomposition  $u=g\circ f$ means $A=BC$.

Comment: I think this is just restating the property rather than proving it. How is you "if and only if" claim proved?

Comment: Through the canonical factorisation of a linear map $u\colon E\rightarrow F $ as $E\rightarrow \operatorname{Im}u\hookrightarrow F$. I didn't say what I propose is a full proof for beginners, rather a sketch for them. There remains to prove there's an injection from $\operatorname{Im}u$ into $\mathbf R^r$ (that's the hypothesis on rank $A$).

Comment: I think giving a proof sketch in lieu of a proof is not for beginners (which OP appears to be). I admit my proof also might be unsettling to OP, but at least it is not terse. As you can see there are quite some details, and the "if" and "only if" parts really are different.

Comment: @Marc van Leeuwen: I finally wrote more details. I really think it has to be given as an appendix, to let the structural idea visible.