# Show that $\operatorname{rank}(A)=r$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $r$ be the smallest integer such that $A=BC$ for some $m\times r$ matrix $B$ and some $r\times n$ matrix $C$. Show that $\operatorname{rank}(A)=r$

Take $x \in \operatorname{Row}(A)$. So $x$ is a linear combination of the rows of $C$, and so $\operatorname{Row}(A)\subset\operatorname{Row}(C)$. Thus $\operatorname{row \,rank}(A)\leq \operatorname{row \,rank}(C).$

This is what I have so far, I'm not sure whether this is even correct though or where to go next.

Comment: To go next? Look up "rank factorisation" $A=BC$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Could you expand on this? I've spent some time looking over rank factorisation but I'm still not seeing exactly how this helps me here.

Comment: See [this MSE-question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1154442/ranka-leq-r-iff-there-are-b-and-c-such-that-a-bc); since $r$ is "the smallest such that $A=BC$", it gives ${\rm rank}(A)=r$ for your question.